# Do these sentences mean the same

Tags: meaning

> We have not begun shipping yet because, unfortunately, there **was** a delay in getting the right sized mailers. We are shipping out soon now that the problem **had been** resolved!

> We have not begun shipping yet because, unfortunately, there **had been** a delay in getting the right sized mailers. We are shipping out soon now that the problem **was** resolved!

Does these sentences mean  the same ? Is the  only difference on emphasize:  one insist on the resolution (first one) and the second on the end of the delay

Comment: I think the second one is better because the delay came before the resolution . May be we can write was a delay and was resolved with no emphasize

Comment: The first one was written by a native speaker so I thought it was right but in fact  I did not  understand  the use of past perfect at the end .

Comment: Could we write " We are shipping out soon now that the problem is  resolved"

Comment: It was quite possibly a typo "had" for "has",  the s and d keys are next to each other on the keyboard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no need for a past perfect at all. You use the past perfect when speaking about events at a time in the past, but you want to refer to an event that occurred before that time.  Here you are not talking about an event that occurred before the past time that you were talking about.  It's just something that happened. You could use past tense or present perfect, "was a delay" or "has been a delay"

At the end you are talking about now, so you should use the present perfect. "The problem has been resolved."

Also, there is no particular exclamation so no exclamation mark at the end.